Do countries other than Australia use the term "boomerang aid"?
Boomerang aid is described in Australia is spending less in foreign aid, but experts say money's only part of the problem as "when government contracts are provided to Australian-based third-party organisations to implement overseas development programs". It's a metaphor where the money appears to go from aid donor to the aid recipient country, but comes back to the original country, like how some boomerangs return to their thrower.
Do other countries (other than Australia, New Zealand, and recipients of aid from Australia) use the term, and if not, is it because they use another term, or that they don't use a term for the alleged phenomenon?

Here's an example in a non-Australian context but Google suggests it's far more common in Australia (e.g. if you search websites that cover multiple countries like The Guardian or BBC, all or most hits are related to Australia). OTOH, ignoring the name, I think this is more or less the default for foreign aid these days. But maybe it's become a political issue in Australia in a way it's not in other English-speaking countries. That said, it's worth checking the academic literature.

The term tied aid seems to be used in many places for something similar.

money that a rich country lends to a poor country, on condition that
the poor country spends the money on goods from the rich country

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tied-aid

Tied aid is a kind of foreign aid. It must be spent on products and
services provided by companies from the country providing the aid (the
donor country) or in a group of specified countries.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tied_aid
Ties That Bind: Tied Aid and Economic Growth
